# URL re-direction issue

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am validating a few URL's together using data driver and some are getting redirected still prints 200 response. In this case, the test case needs to fail and mention the reason for failure.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Code snippet:

```
create session  current_session     ${URL}

${Response}=  get request     current_session  /${gmail}
```

Here, I need to verify, if the URL has navigated to right page without any redirection. I using the data driver library.

Comment: which library are you using , this is not a selenium key word

Comment: @PDHide it is a GUI application but im using the requests library as i have to validate the response body and code that I receive from the URL. Any advise on how do i validate if the URLnavigates to right page without any redirection?

Comment: @BenceKaulics it is a GUI application but i need to get the response of URL that am passing to it. In that way, i also need to verify if the URL is directing to right page or not? without any redirection.

Comment: @PDHide so ideally, the requirement is i need to print all the responses from the URL that i pass.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should separate your test cases. You should have one (or more) for verifying the response body and another one for verifying the URL redirection.

For the latter one I would definitely use SeleniumLibrary.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Redirect Test
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/    Firefox
    Location Should Be     https://stackoverflow.com/
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

But if you would like to use RequestsLibrary for that one as well, the returned object has an `url` and a `status_code` attribute that could be used for verification.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Redirect Test With Requests
    Create Session    SO    https://stackoverflow.com/
    ${response}=    Get Request    SO    /tags
    Log    ${response.status_code}
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${response.status_code}    200
    Log    ${response.url}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.url}    https://stackoverflow.com/tags
    [Teardown]    Delete All Sessions
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. But my issue is i have so many URL's and some are getting redirected still prints 200 response. In this case, the test case needs to fail and mention the reason for redirection. Can you advise on this please?

Comment: @Harini This test also checks the URL in the reponse not just the code. So if the code is 200 but the URL is not right the test will fail. As for the reason of the redirect I do not know if that is included in the reponse.

Comment: @Harini As far as I see URL redirections have their own response code, if in your case it is still `200`, then I am not sure if you have anything else to find out why the redirection happened. If it is considered a bug in the tested application, then I suppose it could provide debug outputs, for example in a browser console etc.